# How can I mirror the backup that win7 backup and recovery makes to another location, after the backup has been completed?

Tags: windows-7, backup

Since Win7's backup and recovery will only copy its files to one location, being able to copy the files to another location would add additional protection to data. How can one mirror the backup that windows backup and recovery makes to another location, say, a network share, or another removable disc? A script using Robocopy, or?

Comment: Both of your ideas would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With robocopy, create a script with the following:

```
@echo off robocopy D:\source E:\destination /MIR /W:60 /R:10
```

Use windows task scheduler to run script whenever you want.

EDIT: the files that windows backup is making need admin access, so the script must be run as admin.